# Do I need to remove cap nails before re-roofing?

Tags: roof, roofing, nails, underlayment

If I have existing decking with old tar paper that I want to remove the tar paper and install synthetic underlayment, do I need to remove all existing cap nails in addition to the tar paper or can I leave the cap nails if none are protruding?
There are literally a thousand cap nails in place.
thanks in advance for advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's between you and your roofing manufacturer. The new underlayment may be more likely to wear through on the protruding caps, nuking your warranty. (Plastic caps are *always* protruding somewhat.)

I'd hire a couple teenagers to pull them. With a cat's paw nail puller it shouldn't take long. Many re-roof jobs I've done have required several thousand roofing nails being pulled individually as well.

Comment: I wouldn't put teenagers on my roof.  Way too much liability.  Only licensed and insured contractors go on my roof.

Comment: Cats paw works great.+